# DOCKER CONTAINER: stat: cannot statx '/tmp/postgresql-common.UsZnjQ': Operation not permitted

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am running a docker image on AWS ECS, but when trying to upgrade a version of a lib I'm getting the error:

```
Creating config file /etc/postgresql-common/createcluster.conf with new version
stat: cannot statx '/tmp/postgresql-common.UsZnjQ': Operation not permitted
dpkg: error processing package postgresql-common (--configure):
 installed postgresql-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of postgresql-server-dev-13:
 postgresql-server-dev-13 depends on postgresql-common (>= 142~); however:
  Package postgresql-common is not configured yet.
```

My docker command is as follows:

RUN apt install -y libxml2-dev 
libxslt-dev 
libpq5 
tzdata 
libsqlite3-dev 
postgresql-server-dev-13 
postgresql-client 
git 
shared-mime-info 
tree \
cron 
rsyslog

I tried to run a chmod before but with no sucess.

```
RUN chmod -R 777 /tmp
```

Any ideas of what can it be?

Comment: (`/tmp` should normally be mode 1777, with an extra permission bit, and you should not normally change that.  You should almost never `chmod 0777` anything.)

Comment: I did it just as a test, so see if it was something related.